# The reason Aaron's two sons died

Tags: death, parashat-shemini

Why did Aaron's two elder sons die? I've heard that there are many reasons offered, and would appreciate knowing as many as possible.

Comment: I only know of ten. 1 They went into the kodshai kodoshim. 2 They brought a korbon what they were not told to. 3 They didnt ask each other beforehand. 4 They were drunk 5. They did not have the correct clothes.6 They had not washed their hands and feet.7 They did not have children. 8 They were not married.9 Their hair was too long. 10. They paskened in front of moshe rabeinu.

Comment: I think that this is a polling question which should probably be closed as "not constructive"

Comment: @Daniel, there are many, many good questions in Judaism (and on this site) that have many equally good answers (each). E.g. [these](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=[parshanut-torah-comment]+is%3Aq+why) or [these](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=[minhag]+is%3Aq+why). [The FAQ list](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) says not to ask "**subjective** questions where... every answer is equally valid" (emphasis added), but this is not subjective.

Comment: Maybe a better way to ask this question would be to list your ten reasons and see whether or not anybody can provide you with the sources for all of them (assuming you don't know them already)? Here's an eleventh one for you: because they ate and drank while in the presence of God (Exodus 24:11).

Answer (score 1):

> תניא ר"א אומר לא מתו בני אהרן עד שהורו הלכה בפני משה רבן מאי דרוש ונתנו בני אהרן הכהן אש על המזבח אמרו אף על פי שהאש יורדת מן השמים מצוה להביא מן ההדיוט

Rabbi Eliezer said that the sons of Aharon died because they ruled the ruled Halacha in front of their teacher.

[Eiruvin 63a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=3&daf=63&format=text)